# Swift convert object that is NSNumber to Double

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code in Swift and it works, but I would think there is a better way to get my object from NSNumber and convert it to  a Double:

```
var rating: NSNumber
var ratingDouble: Double

rating = self.prodResult?.prodsInfo.prodList[indexPath.row].avgRating as NSNumber!!

ratingDouble = Double(rating.doubleValue)
```

Comment: Does ratingDouble = rating not work?  Swift should support bridging the two.

Comment: If I do that: error: 'NSNumber' is not convertible to 'Double'.  But I can do this:  ratingDouble = rating.doubleValue

Answer (score 75, accepted):

**Update**

Swift's behavior here has changed quite a bit since 1.0.  Not that it was that easy before, but Swift has made it harder to convert between number types because it wants you to be explicit about what to do with precision loss.  Your new choices now look like this:

```
var rating: NSNumber
var ratingDouble: Double

ratingDouble = rating as! Double // 1
ratingDouble = Double(exactly: rating)! // 2

ratingDouble = Double(truncating: rating) // 3
ratingDouble = rating.doubleValue // 4

if let x = rating as? Double { // 5
    ratingDouble = x
}

if let x = Double(exactly: rating) { // 6
    ratingDouble = x
}
```

1. This calls [`Double._forceBridgeFromObjectiveC`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a28c9d62138e5386ba9341332af218cd232c455e/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSNumber.swift#L509) which calls `Double(exactly:)` with `Double`, `Int64`, or `UInt64` based on the stored type in `rating`.  It will fail and crash the app if the number isn't exactly representable as a `Double`. E.g. `UInt64.max` has more digits than `Double` can store, so it'll crash.
2. This is exactly the same as 1 except that it may also crash on `NaN` since that check isn't included.
3. This function always returns a `Double` but will lose precision in cases where 1 and 2 would crash.  [This literally just calls `doubleValue` when passing in an `NSNumber`.](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a28c9d62138e5386ba9341332af218cd232c455e/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSNumber.swift#L484)
4. Same as 3.
5. This is like 1 except that instead of crashing the app, it'll return nil and the inside of the statement won't be evaluated.
6. Same as 5, but like 2 will return nil if the value is `NaN`.

If you know your data source is dealing in doubles, 1-4 will probably all serve you about the same.  3 and 4 would be my first choices though.

---

**Old Answer for Swift 1 and 2**

There are several things you can do:

```
var rating: NSNumber
var ratingDouble: Double

ratingDouble = rating as Double   // 1
ratingDouble = Double(rating)     // 2
ratingDouble = rating.doubleValue // 3
```

1. The first item takes advantage of `Objective-C`bridging which allows `AnyObject` and `NSNumber` to be cast as [`Double|Float|Int|UInt|Bool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_45).
2. The second item presumably goes through a constructor with the signature `init(_ number: NSNumber)`.  I couldn't find it in the module or docs but passing `AnyObject` in generated an error that it cannot be implicitly downcast to `NSNumber` so it must be there and not just bridging.
3. The third item doesn't employ language features in the same way.  It just takes advantage of the fact that `doubleValue` returns a `Double`.

One benefit of 1 is that it also works for `AnyObject` so your code could be:

```
let ratingDouble = self.prodResult!.prodsInfo.prodList[indexPath.row].avgRating! as Double
```

Note that I removed the `?` from your function and moved the `!` in.  Whenever you use ! you are eschewing the safety of `?` so there's no reason to do both together.

Comment: The first part works, but the code:
let ratingDouble = self.prodResult!.prodsInfo.prodList[indexPath.row].avgRating! as Double

does not, Xcode isn't telling me the exact error, it just crashes there, any ideas about why?

Comment: Your app is crashing or Xcode is crashing? What's the type of `self.prodResult!.prodsInfo.prodList[indexPath.row].avgRating`

Comment: The app is crashing.  The type is NSNumber.  It stops with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but right before that is: _dynamicCastUnknownClass(swift::OpaqueValue*, void*, swift::Metadata const*, swift::DynamicCastFlags).

Comment: This solution is no longer valid with Swift 3 and the removal of type bridging

Comment: @MarcoPappalardo Which part isn't working?  The above code works for me in Swift 3.0 (Xcode 8.2).  Implicit bridging (i.e., `ratingDouble = rating`) was removed forever ago but explicit bridging works.

Comment: @BrianNickel yep! sorry :)
most of the other types require to use as! or as? to explicitly show failability. I was sure that explicit bridging also required it. Ups :D

Comment: Thank you for item 1. I had observed this behavior but wasn't sure why it worked. Now I know.  :-)