# How to get a UIColor from Associative Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, mobile, ibeacon

I have this array with some UIColors:

```
let colors = [
    35302: UIColor(red: 66/255, green: 55/255, blue: 101/255, alpha: 1),
    53350: UIColor(red: 158/255, green: 218/255, blue: 222/255, alpha: 1),
    54747: UIColor(red: 158/255, green: 222/255, blue: 189/255, alpha: 1)
]
```

Now, I'm trying to access some index in Array:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
    let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown }
    if(knownBeacons.count > 0) {
        let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as! CLBeacon
        self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[closestBeacon.minor]
    }
}
```

The line:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[closestBeacon.minor]
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type '[Int: UIColor]' with an index of type 'NSNumber'
```

I'm trying to make a HelloWorld with my new Beacons and I'm stuck in this part.
I would like to understand how this really work.

Thanks

Comment: The Swift/Objective-C term for the collection object you're using is dictionary, not "associative array". It's a good idea to learn the "native" terms for things. (Not trying to be difficult. I'm familiar with the term associative array from computer science, but it still threw me for a moment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `NSNumber` but array requires `Int` as index. Choose one of the following:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[closestBeacon.minor as Int]
self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[closestBeacon.minor.integerValue]
self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[Int(closestBeacon.minor)]
```

You could also check this question [Swift convert object that is NSNumber to Double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279032/swift-convert-object-that-is-nsnumber-to-double)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! ;D

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of things, closestBeacon.minor is an NSNumber, while colors are indexed by Int.

You could use closestBeacon.minor.integerValue