# Unable to bridge NSNumber to Float

Tags: swift, nsnumber

I'm runtime errors on my existing project when migrating versions of Xcode. Can someone help with this? Is my typecasting wrong?

Code:

```
let x    = d[ChildItem.KEY_LOOK] as! NSArray as Array
let y    = d[ChildItem.KEY_COOR] as! NSArray as Array
let item = ChildItem(x as! [Float], y as! [Float])
```

Error:

> Thread 5: Fatal error: Unable to bridge NSNumber to Float

I know how to cast an NSNumber to a Float as I found on SO ([Unable to bridge NSNumber to Float in JSON parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610727/unable-to-bridge-nsnumber-to-float-in-json-parsing)):

```
    if let n = d.value(forKey: "probability") as? NSNumber {
    let f = n.floatValue }
```

How can I do this for an NSNumber array?

In each of the d[] keys there are JSON strings like this:

> d[ChildItem.KEY_LOOK] = [465918.2, 5681518.0,4462.3203]

Comment: What is this? `let 1 = ...` doesn't look like valid syntax.

Comment: Right - fixed now.

Comment: I have to say, this is really ugly code. First of all, you should avoid force casting, that causes crashes. Then you're force-casting to `NSArray` and then to `Array`, when casting to `NSArray` is unnecessary. `KEY_LOOK` and `KEY_COOR` are plain ugly to look at, I would create a `Key` enum in `ChildItem` and add constants in there, so it'd look like this `ChildItem.Key.Look`. And finally, we don't know how `d` is declared, or how you got it's contents, so we can only guess what your error is, you should provide us with that info and avoid using NS-prefixed classes when working with Swift.

Comment: Please post the contents of `d`.

Comment: @Vadian - you can see contents of 'd' at the SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610727/unable-to-bridge-nsnumber-to-float-in-json-parsing

Comment: I mean the `d` in your first example. And `value(forKey...as NSNumber)` is horrible code.

Comment: @Vadian - d content: d["s_i_coord"]. What it is is going through a JSON tree.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out. Without knowing the **real** contents of `d` (and its static type) I can't help.

Comment: What happens if you skip the first cast to NSArray and just have `let x = d[ChildItem.KEY_LOOK] as? Array`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Type cast to `Array` is pointless. A JSON array is at least `[Any]`, in many cases `[[String:Any]]` and in this particular case it's supposed to be `[Float]`.

Comment: @vadian, yes of course. I didn't think that through, I guess I just got frustrated by the double casting.

Comment: I also tried: let y    = d[ChildItem.KEY_COOR] as! [Float] and get same error.

Comment: Unless you clarify your question and show us what kind of data you have in `d` for those two keys this is pointless. Also in your question you say you're having problem compiling the project but this is a runtime error, very confusing and what is this about "...migrating versions if Xcode"?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson - see above

Comment: Where? I don't understand.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson - up in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the floatValue property of NSNumber, not casting directly.

Comment: How would the syntax be written to do this on an Array?

Comment: Can you provide me with sample code? I'd be grateful.

Comment: something like this?
let num = NSNumber(value: 8)
let arr = [num,num,num,num,num]
let result = arr.map{ $0.floatValue }

Comment: Basically you should not use `NSNumber` in Swift at all unless the API requires it. This API certainly doesn't. (I didn't downvote by the way)

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have an array of numbers you got from the server calls like this

```
d[ChildItem.KEY_LOOK] = [465918.2, 5681518.0,4462.3203] // from your example
```

you can do the following

```
//As from your example that can be directly convert to Array of Doubles like this
if let arrayOfDoubles = d[ChildItem.KEY_LOOK] as? [Double] {
        debugPrint(arrayOfDoubles)
}
```

And if for some reason you want those to be [NSNumber] then you can do like this

```
if let arrayOfNumbers = d[ChildItem.KEY_LOOK] as? [NSNumber] {

        //to make this array of double
     let doubleArray = arrayOfNumbers.map { $0.doubleValue }

        //to make int
     let intArray = arrayOfNumbers.map { $0.intValue }

     ... and so on
}
```